# Can feenableexcept hurt a program performance?

Tags: c, x86, x86-64, fenv

I would like to enable floating point exceptions on some critical code using fpeenableexcept or _MM_SET_EXCEPTION_MASK (on Mac OS X).

Is there any case on x86/x86-64 where changing the enabled exceptions will hurt the program performance *when no error occurs*?

I am only asking about numerical code after the exception is changed and code which is not throwing any exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some times running my application with the exception enables, I did not encounter any performance regression.